# Can't get my total to print outside my for loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just running some simple code and for the life of me I can't get the variable "total" to print after my for loop.  I'm returning it, but to no avail.  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
#pypractice.py
import math
import pdb

def main():

    n = eval(input("Please enter a number: "))
    total = 0

    #pdb.set_trace()
    for x in range(1, n):
        total = x + total
        print(total)
    return total
    print(total)
    #pdb.set_trace()


main()
```

Comment: `return` ends a function. Put all `print` calls (and all other code) _before_ `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Execution stops at the presence of a `return` statement. Switch the order:

```
# for loop stuff
print(total)
return total
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` function will stop execution and **return** the value `total`, so it will never reach your final print.

As the total is returned to the caller, you can just print it there.

```
#pypractice.py
import math
import pdb

def main():

    n = eval(input("Please enter a number: "))
    total = 0

    #pdb.set_trace()
    for x in range(1, n):
        total = x + total
        print(total)
    return total
    #pdb.set_trace()

print(main())
```